# How can I mount a USB flash drive on my Acer Iconia?

Tags: usb-host-mode, acer-iconia-a500

I have an Acer Iconia A500 tablet with Android 3.1. I cannot mount any USB flash drives. File Manager HD and other similar apps display "Directory is empty" in `/mnt/usb_storage/`. I have tried use a flash drive formatted FAT32, and my USB port works (I've checked with a USB mouse).  How can I get this to work?

Comment: What types of drives have you tried? There are some (mostly older) drives that won't work even on a PC without custom drivers.

Comment: It is just flash memory. USB Flash Silicon-Power 8 Gb. It works on all PC without drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use File Manager HD and do the following Steps :

1. On the **panel at the left** tap **Storage**.
2. **On the panel** at the **top right** press the **Up arrow until the first directory entry is asec**.
3. **Now scroll down through the directory** and you should see usb_storage.

   4.**Tap usb_storage and you should see your data.**

Hope i will help.

From : http://androidforums.com/acer-iconia-tab-a500/358421-iconia-a500-cant-browse-through-usb-flash-drive.html

Answer (score 1):

The USB host mount script seems to be on the flaky side. My tab reports the drive is inserted but is not mounted to `/mnt/usb_storage`. A reboot is the only way I've found to fix this.

Answer (score -3):

Being 8GB I believe it could be a way the flash is using mass storage.
Although all drives should be seen, not all are setup by each manufacture the same.
Have you tried to format the flash as a 2GB fat32 to determine mass storage feature for the drive or for the tab?
I assume that this flash is valid as you have been able to format it.
How do any other flash drives work?
I also found quite a few HP flash drives have issues as they attempt to install the extra software from the minor partition.